# Tkinter button not returning value from function

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter

I am currently trying to create a small UI for a function that returns some value from a data frame based on the string that has been entered. The string is split and each individual substring is looked up in my data frame using iloc. The issue is, when calling this function using a button in Tkinter, nothing is being returned. It works fine without Tkinter so I am unsure where the error is occurring.

```
master = Tk()
e1 = Entry(master)

list_of_inputs = e1.get().split()

def show_entry_fields():
    i=0
    while (i<len(list_of_inputs)):
        return (backend.loc[backend['Keyword'] == list_of_inputs[i]]) 
        i=i+1

Label(master, text="Enter Title").grid(row=0)

e1.grid(row=0, column=1)

Button(master, text='Show', command=show_entry_fields).grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=W, pady=4)

mainloop( )
```

Comment: Where do you expect it to be returned to?

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things:

- You are checking the value of your Entry before the user has a chance to fill it in. You should get the user input only when the button is pressed.
- Your while loop in the `show_entry_fields()` function will always run once regardless of how many inputs provided, since you put a return statement inside the loop
- Your handler function has to modify an existing data structure or graphical component, if you return your result you cant collect it

Possible implementation:

```
master = Tk()
e1 = Entry(master)


def show_entry_fields():
    list_of_inputs = e1.get().split()
    result = []
    for entry in list_of_inputs:
        result.append(backend.loc[backend['Keyword']] == entry)
    # Alternatively, you can create the list with
    # result = [backend.loc[backend['Keyword']] == entry for entry in list_of_inputs]
    # Here, deal with the result    

Label(master, text="Enter Title").grid(row=0)
e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
Button(master, text='Show', command=show_entry_fields).grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=W, pady=4)
mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. That seems to have worked. The issue now is that the input from e1, once the string has been split and stored, the loc function is now returning an Error (at least it is giving me something): 

KeyError: 'None of [0 ... learningcase\nName: Keyword, Length: 52667, dtype: object] are in the [index]'

I tested strings that definitely exist in the backend data frame.